# Can not find or load main class from cmd when using absolute paths

Tags: java, path, cmd, classpath

I can not run my Java class from the command prompt using absolute paths.

In the cmd, when I CD to `C:\Automation\XML_wrapper\bin` and type `java wrapper` it works.

When I at in `C:\` and type `C:\program files\java\jdk.xxx\bin\java C:\Automation\XML_wrapper\bin\wrapper` it does not work.

I tried variants of the java command, including quotes and including `.exe`.

I also tried variants of the java class including adding `-cp C:\Automation\XML_Wrapper\bin` and including `.class` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a *class name* to `java` - not a *file name*. You'll also probably need to provide a class *path* to say where to find the file:

```
java -cp C:\Automation\XML_wrapper\bin wrapper
```

The `-cp` argument just tells the JVM where to load classes from - it can be a sequence of directories and/or jar files. The `wrapper` part is the name of the class, which is more commonly something like `com.acme.SomeApplication` - that's class `SomeApplication` within the `com.acme` package. (A class name of just `wrapper` would break Java naming conventions. It's not illegal, just unconventional.)